# How to add a MapPolygon to Windows Phone 8 map?

Tags: mapping, windows-phone-8

I've recently downloaded and installed Windows 8 OS along with Visual Studio 2012 and I'm trying to port an old project I built on Windows Phone 7 to WP8.

It has a map that originally had a MapPolygon in it so that whenever you zoom in/out the polygon was always proportional based on the zoom level.

MapPolygon is still a valid class using the new Map control (not Bing Maps Control) but I have no idea how to add it to a map to get the same features/properties.

I think it has to do with the MapElements which should allow to add a shape to the map in the following fashion.

```
        MapPolygon shape = new MapPolygon();

        shape.Path.Add(new GeoCoordinate(55.859185825719055, 2.2946083545684877));
        shape.Path.Add(new GeoCoordinate(55.858185825719055, 2.2956083545684877));
        shape.Path.Add(new GeoCoordinate(55.857185825719055, 2.2946083545684877));
        shape.Path.Add(new GeoCoordinate(55.858185825719055, 2.2936083545684877));
        shape.StrokeThickness = 3;
        shape.StrokeColor = Colors.Blue; 
        shape.FillColor = Colors.Black; 

        map1.MapElements.Add(shape);
```

Nothing shows on the map.

I've also tried to add a Grid to a MapOverlay to a MapLayer to a Map but I have no idea how/where to add the MapPolygon in this way.

Comment: Note you can still use Bing Maps in WP8, just reference Maps dll in this folder:  Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ridiculous mistake. 
My map wasn't centered at the same place as the GeoCoordinates were added to the shapes path.